# Evaluate Complex line integral, Solution Verification

Tags: complex-analysis

Define $C$ to be a simple closed curve containing the points $0,1, \dots , k \in \mathbb{C}$. And define $I_{1} = \oint_{C} \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{k} (z-i)}{z} dz$ and $I_{2} = \oint_{C} \frac{dz}{\prod_{i=0}^{k} (z-i)}$. I got (using the residue theorem) that $I_{2} = 2 \pi i \cdot \left[ \sum_{t=0}^{k} \frac{1}{\prod_{\substack{i=0 \\ i \ne t}}^{k} (t-i)} \right]$ and $I_{1} = 2 \pi i (-1)^{k} k!$. I was wondering if this is correct and if there is a better form for $I_{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

For $I_2$, notice that $C$ enclosing all $0, 1, \cdots, k$ implies that
$$ I_2 = \oint_C \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\prod_{i=0}^k (z-i)} = \oint_{|z|=R} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\prod_{i=0}^k (z-i)} $$
where $R$ is large enough that $|z|=R$ encloses $0,1,\cdots,k$ too.
$$ \left|\oint_{|z|=R} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\prod_{i=0}^k (z-i)}\right| \le 2\pi R \max_{|z|=R} \left| \frac{1}{\prod_{i=0}^k (z-i)} \right| = O(R^{-k}) \rightarrow 0 $$
if $k\ge 1$. Therefore $I_2 = 0$ for $k\ge 1$, and $I_2 = 2\pi i$ for $k=0$.

Comment: Wait but why can't we use the residue theorem?

Comment: @user100101212 You can. The expression that you got is zero.

Comment: You've already got the correct result and it could be simplified to $0$.